# None is being ignored, don't know why

Tags: python-3.x

I do not understand why I am getting those results with this code:

```
print(12, end = None) ; print(34)
```

The output is:

```
12
34
```

None is ignored.

But when I do this:

```
print(None)
```

It prints `None`

So why is this happening?

Comment: Think of `None` as the lack of a value, rather than a value itself. In this case, it means, "I am not giving `print` an end value," rather than, "I am telling `print` to print nothing at the end." The empty string is a string of nothing, while `None` is the lack of a string.

Comment: Then why is None not being ignored when I do print(None). Shouldn't it show the same behavior and print nothing again?

Comment: When you pass it to `print` as `end`, it doesn't print nothing (which would be a value rather than the lack of a value), but rather `\n`. On the other hand, `print(None)` can be interpreted as either "I'm not telling you what to print" or "I'm telling you to print `None`". The second is a more useful interpretation (you might print a variable and find out that its value is `None`), so the second is used by `print`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `None` is the default value, and hence the one it checks for to see if no argument has been passed. If you want to omit the newline then pass `''` instead.